# How to add CSS (padding) to website in a webView

Tags: java, android, css, android-webview

I have been wondering how I can set padding-bottom (Custom CSS) to work with a webpage from RemoteConfig (there is a URL). I do not have the access to a webpage, therefore I can not edit it directly in the source files.

Here is my code:

```
public class PlayoffsFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private WebView webView;

    public static PlayoffsFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
        PlayoffsFragment fragment = new PlayoffsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_playoffs, container, false);
    setActionBar();
    setViews();
    setViewContents();
        return rootView; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        hideCalendarMenuItem(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void setActionBar() {
        showActionBar();
        setContentMarginOff();
        changeToolbarBackground(R.color.transparent);
        changeToolbarIconsColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white)); }


    @Override
    protected void setViews() {
        webView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
        webView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setViewContents() {
        webView.loadUrl(BuildConfig.WEB_URL);
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you could retrive the web page-source code using http request then parse that and your custom css into webview.

Comment: @AhmadBudairi well I will try that. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to do it. For anyone wanting to do something similar, here is the code I updated:

```
@Override
protected void setViews() {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
    webView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            injectCSS();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void setViewContents() {
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

private void injectCSS() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getContext().getAssets().open("styles.css");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                "style.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                "parent.appendChild(style)" +
                "})()");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I have created styles.css in Assets folder.